# Unable to register VM through Prism Navigation

Tags: prism, .net-core-3.1, wpf-core

I'm creating WPF Core 3.1 app using Prism 7. In one of the view I am trying to register the view model for PRISM navigation through:

```
containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ViewA, ViewAViewModel>();
```

And when required I do request to PRISM navigation service to navigate to the view using Region Manager

```
_regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.ContentRegion, "ViewA");
```

Navigation to the view is completed and I'm able to see the view on the defined region but the view model is not assigned to the view.

I tried to manually register the view model using the ViewModelLocationProvider but still the view model is not assigned.

```
ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<ViewA, ViewAViewModel>();
```

But if I use the PRISM Autowire property in the view then the view model is discovered and assigned to the view.

```
prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
```

View model class declared using IConfirmNavigationRequest interface required for navigation request handling

```
public class ViewAViewModel : RegionViewModelBase , IConfirmNavigationRequest
```

I am unable to figureout what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I see wrong is that you would need to use the interface `INavigationAware`, not `IConfirmNavigationRequest`. I assume `RegionViewModelBase` implements `BindableBase` already.

```
public class ViewAViewModel : RegionViewModelBase, INavigationAware
```

Comment: IConfirmNavigationRequest implementes INavigationAware interface.

Comment: @Bluecomb I was just following on what Brian Lagunas gives in his tutorials. Usually when something isn't working, I boil it down to its "base" form, see if it works, and then start modifying to the point where it doesn't work anymore and try to figure out why. As I mentioned, I don't see why the code wouldn't work if you did everything correctly. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.